# applescript: how to copy real file instead of alias, but recursively

Tags: macos, applescript, alias

I am using the following script to copy certain folder content from my hard-drive on a usb-Stick. Since the folder content might change, I am using aliases.

The script used to work perfectly, but since I had to make changes in my folder structure, I now have sometimes an alias of an alias (workaround of the script, won´t go into that).

Problem is that the script seems to only convert the first level of alias-folders, but if there is an alias for a file within an alias for a folder, it copies the file-alias.

I wonder if it is possible to tell the script to recursively go through every level of the folder (ie every file) and copy the original file instead.

Thanks!

Peter

ps: exemplary folder structure of source folder:

alias of folder 1

```
          alias of folder 1-1

                   alias of file a, alias of file b
```

alias of folder 2

```
         alias of file c
```

```````````
--> first a dialogue

display notification "hello, get folder ready"
delay 5 --> allow time for the notification to trigger

set theDialogText to "choose source"
display dialog theDialogText



--> Result: {button returned:"OK"}


--> now computing

set the backupSource to (choose folder) as alias

set theDialogText to "choose destination"


display dialog theDialogText

--> Result: {button returned:"OK"}


set the backupDestination to (choose folder) as alias

display notification "maybe this takes a while..."

delay 6 --> allow time for the notification to trigger

--> now copy

tell application "Finder"

    activate
    with timeout of 600 seconds --> equeals 10 Minutes

        set everyAlias to every item of folder backupSource
        repeat with thisAlias in everyAlias

            set originalFile to (original item of thisAlias)
            duplicate originalFile to backupDestination

        end repeat
    end timeout
end tell
``````````

I feel that the the line "repeat thisAlias in everyAlias" doesn´t do its job and goes only one level down, ie it converts the alias on the first level and not all other aliases within this alias-folder
```````````

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a quick fix, but rather programming advice: it's time to add debugging. In this case, I suspect your script is not operating on the files you intend to use. So what's it doing instead?

For example, near the beginning,
`set debugOn to true`
or better
`property debugOn : true`

Then right before your `duplicate` command,

```
if debugOn then display dialog ¬
     "Copying thisAlias: " & return & (thisAlias as text) & return & ¬
     "of originalFile: " & return & originalFile buttons "OK" default button 1
```

…and so forth. You can leave these `if debugOn then`… checks throughout your code with dialogs or even different modes of behavior, and just change it to `property debugOn : false` once it's working. Having it all there is also great for the inevitable day you need to edit the script, but it's aged enough you've forgotten all its nuances.

Comment: Thanks Joel, will try.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this following AppleScript code will help you accomplish what you're looking for?

```
tell application "Finder"
    set sourceFolder to choose folder with prompt "CHOOSE SOURCE"
    set destinationFolder to choose folder with prompt "CHOOSE DESTINATION"
    set nestedFolders to a reference to (entire contents of sourceFolder)
    set aliasFiles to a reference to every alias file of nestedFolders
    set aliasFiles to contents of aliasFiles
    repeat with i from 1 to count of aliasFiles
        set thisItem to item i of aliasFiles
        if not (exists of original item of thisItem) then
            delete thisItem
        end if
    end repeat
    set aliasFiles to a reference to every alias file of nestedFolders
    set originalFiles to (original item of aliasFiles) as alias list
    duplicate originalFiles to destinationFolder
end tell
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your contribution, it does copy a lot, but it´s hard to compary folders for completeness as the original folder structure is not maintained...Is there a way to do this? It has some folders, but not the fully hierarchy from the top...thanks!